# My website appears in Google in a wrong way

Tags: html, web, seo, search-engine

I published my first website and I am still trying to solve its problems. I have mainly two questions regarding my website:

1. I have published my website and it suddenly appears in Google, but not in the way I want. For example, my site is `www.mysite.com`, but in Google `www.mysite.com/contact.html` or `www.mysite.com/blog.html` come before the original website URL.
2. I would like my website to be displayed like a website. (Please, write `envato` on Google and you will see the first result. Main link is on the top, sub-links are below it). How can I achieve this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO without a programming specific component. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ would be a more appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not right way to appear in Google. Google decides in which order it presents your pages according to what it thinks is best for its users. You have no control on this. However, you can influence this by creating more backlinks to your preferred URLs and focus on its content too. Make it more valuable than other pages for example.

This is a SEO related question. Next time, it should be asked on [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

1. Google will rank what they deem the most relevant result the highest. If they're ranking your contact or blog pages higher, chances are there's not much useful content on the home page.
2. You can't affect this. Google does it based on an algorithm, and only for sites where they deem it to be sufficiently useful.

Answer (score 0):

Optimise your home page for the keywords / phrases for which related pages are showing. You cannot control what Google deems relevant as per their algo.

Re-optimise your inner pages (unwanted links) for related phrases. Building a site-map with proper hierarchy also helps.

Also, are your inner pages within sub-folders or in the open folder along with your index.html? Defining a proper 'folder-drill-down' bread-crumb also helps search engines in understanding page hierarchy and displaying it like so.